# Computer Build for VM's: Slow behavior normal?

Tags: windows, memory, ssd, cpu, motherboard

I've custom built a computer for work. The main idea (for security reasons mostly) is to use one VM exclusively for work (mainly 3rd party windows applications that work with PostgresSQL) and another VM for everything else (surfing, gaming, etc...). At first, I decided to go with server hardware for reliability issues I had with regular computers in the past. However, I'm finding this build to be slower than what I expected it to be (for the price).

I am considering getting a new regular motherboard/cpu/ram for speed reasons, but I first would like to make sure that this 'slow' behavior is normal.

For comparison, I ran a CPU test (superpi.net - std settings) on my brothers computer (std gaming build i7 3770, ssd, gtx 780) and his computer beat mine for more than 2 minutes.

**Q1** - Do I need to be running a server motherboard on Windows Server 2012? Do I get any benefits for doing so given the purpose of my build? Is Windows 8.1 architectural design utilizing all cores/threads?

**Q2** - Taking away reliability from the equation, is there any benefit on running a couple VM's in a server motherboard? For me trading off reliability for speed is a very appealing option at this point.

As you can see I might had overestimated the amount of reliability I needed when building this computer. Part of that was due to my last computer build having lots of errors and BSOD. There is no reason to believe I can't build a solid and fast regular computer :(.

Any hardware recommendations to go with my GPU/SSD/PSU are appreciated.

**Computer Build**:

Motherboard - [ASUS LGA2011 Intel Z9PE-D8 WS][2]

CPU - 2x [Intel Xeon 6C E5 2620 2.0 GHz](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007H29ECE)

RAM - [Kingston 64GB ECC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0088SSV6G)

SSD - [OCZ RevoDrive 3 x2 480GB][4]

GPU - [Sapphire Radeon Vapor-X HD 7970 GHZ OC 6GB DDR5][5]

PSU - [Corsair AX 850 Watt ATX/EPS Modular 80 PLUS Gold][6]

Comment: Could you clarify? Are you running these VMs inside of Windows, or are you using something along the lines of ESXi?

Comment: I'm running them on Windows 8.1 through VMware Workstation.

Comment: If you have no reason to use the host OS, then you should remove it and use a hypervisor, such as ESXi. You can migrate your current VMs fairly easily from VMWare Workstation to ESXi. You will see a performance increase.

VMs are memory intensive, but you have plenty of RAM. It's possible that the Windows 8 host is not properly making use of the two processors and that could be your bottleneck. Also note that those Intel Xeons should be able to handle whatever load you place on them.

Comment: That's what I would like to know, If I'm getting bottlenecked by the O/S or something else, or if these Xeon processors should be this slow.

Comment: As I understand you question, you are wanting to use the computer as your workstation, rather than a server to remote onto.  I would use Linux/KVM as your host OS, and not Windows 8.  Virtualise your Windows 8 loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your general idea is certainly very sound you really don't want to be running any modern games in a VM. If you want to run some older games, say from from 3-4 years back then then you'll be OK, for older DOS games a VM is often your only way to get them running on modern hardware. [Ben Armstrong at Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2005/01/29/363010.aspx) has lots of blog posts about getting classic games running under Virtual PC/Hyper-V.

Running a VM under VMware Workstation throws away about 15-20% of your available CPU power in a best case scenario. For the GPU it's far worse, you might be lucky to get 50% of the available GPU power in your VM. In your setup the host OS has to own the GPU and has to "share" it with the VM.

If you were to use a hypervisor such as ESXi then you can dedicate the GPU as a passthrough device to a dedicated gaming VM and get close to 100% of expected performance.

ESXi is [free](http://www.vmware.com/products/vsphere-hypervisor) to use but you are going to need a second system that will be a lightweight terminal into the VMs running on the ESXi server.

Comment: I don't do a lot of gaming, and I could just close the VMs and do gaming in the HOST O/S (not ideal for security, I know). By the way, the speed cpu test I ran was done in the Host O/S with no VMs running. I don't switch tasks frequently, I'm either working on the VM, surfing the web on the other VM, or gaming on the host O/S with VMs closed. I will look into the ESXi solution given, although it might be too advanced for me. Remember I just use VMs for security reasons (sandboxed enviroments) and some backup like snapshots features.

Comment: Games aren't the big security problem, browsers are. Make sure you don't use a browser in the host and your security concerns will be lessened. If your VM gets trashed by some malware you can always roll it back to a prior known good point.

Comment: I'd fully expect your brothers 4Ghz i7 to trash your i5 2GHz in a simple CPU test. CPUs don't scale linearly, having 2 x 2GHz CPUs does not get your app running as fast a it will on a 4GHz CPU, you'll be lucky to get them running as fast as a 3GHz CPU.

Comment: Exaclty, thanks for your answers. Keep in mind my original concern is with the speed of the computer. I'm contemplating whether to sell it and buy a regular 1 CPU build instead.

Comment: There is one huge difference between a regular single CPU system and the workstation system that you have and that is reliable RAM. You have ECC which essentially eliminates the chances of your RAM having a brain fart. Many transient app or system crashes can be caused by momentary RAM faults. That's why every server has ECC (or better) RAM.